# Why SNAT works by setting one rules in tables without the rules in PREROUTING chain?

Tags: linux, iptables, nat

I have some questions about SNAT with iptables.
Assume there is one router who plays DHCP server for assign private IPs in my LAN and NAT for the hosts in my LAN can access the public internet.

The router has two interfaces, one "eth0" with dynamic public IP and the other "eth1" with private IP 192.168.0.1 and the subnet is 192.168.0.0/24. Assume the ipv4 packet forwarding is enable on that router. I know I have to set one rule in NAT table for masquerading the source IP of the packet to the public internet from the hosts in my LAN. This rule may looks like the one under.

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`

I understand why I need the rule since the packet from my LAN needs a public IP for internet routing.

But I do not understand why I do not need set another rule in `PREROUTING` chain for the response packets in order to modify their destination IP addresses.

Is the modification of destination address of those response packets a default behavior of the MASQUERADE rule I just set?

And another question is that how iptable know which packets should be modified?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iptables NAT is stateful. Using the 'nat' table will automatically load the *conntrack* system, which keeps a list of active connections and recognizes which packet belongs to which connection. The conntrack system registers internal hooks that work separately from iptables rules, and will automatically transform packets that it recognizes.

(You can see the conntrack state table using `conntrack -L` or via /proc/self/net/nf_conntrack.)

With this system, rules in the 'nat' table actually match only the *initial* packet belonging to each connection, not every single packet. Once the initial packet has been matched, the corresponding conntrack entry is marked as needing NAT (or not) and further packets are automatically transformed without even going through the 'nat' table.

Comment: So the kernel will automatically modify the packet based on the information stored in _contrack_ system and that's why I don't need to set the rules in PREROUTING chain. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. (It's also the same system which lets you have a filter rule that accepts incoming packets belonging to established connections while still blocking new incoming connections.)

Comment: But what about the UDP packet since there is no connection concept in UDP protocol. How would system know this packet is a response for previous UDP request packet?

Comment: The same way that the application itself knows: the response arrives from the same IP address within a certain amount of time and has the same src/dst ports as well. The concept of states doesn't require the concept of connections in the protocol.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have much understanding about it.

Comment: But that's error prone... depending on the UDP connection, you're telling if the remote UDP replies too late, the packet is dropped. Should I always add the PREROUTING rule to be sure? Or should I stop using nat and using mangle and alter directly the header?

Comment: @Alexis: Unlikely to be necessary – most programs are either unaffected, or deal with it at application level. For example, DNS or NTP responses arrive within seconds, and most clients will either retransmit or give up long before the conntrack state expires. Games and video streams send data continuously so the state lifetime keeps being extended. VPNs could indeed have problems with the state expiring when the tunnel goes idle, but that's only an issue for inbound connections over the VPN, and practically all VPN clients support sending keepalive packets when they detect a NAT.

Comment: (Also, this is not really specific to NAT – the same conntrack system, with the same timers, is used to implement stateful firewalls via `-m state` just about everywhere.)

Comment: Understood, thanks!