# Does all traffic go through the iptables PREROUTING (nat) chain?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I put a LOG rule at the beginning of the PREROUTING (nat) chain and the INPUT chain. I see that much more data is logged from the INPUT chain than the PREROUTING.

Is there an explanation for this ? There is much more on the INPUT chain. Is it the case that PREROUTING (nat) is not used for established connections ?

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1271 packets, 166K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  806  119K LOG        all  --  *      *       10.101.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0            LOG flags 0 level 4

Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 53 packets, 3180 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    2   120 LOG        all  --  *      *       10.101.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0            LOG flags 0 level 4
```

Comment: Does https://superuser.com/questions/1416212/why-snat-works-by-setting-one-rules-in-tables-without-the-rules-in-prerouting-ch/ answer the question?